# jQuery animate width from centered x coordinates of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Is possible to `animate()` the width of an element making a smooth center animation?

I mean animate making the element fixed on itself centered on himself x coordinates?

if i do :

```
<a class="animate">hey</a>
$('.animate').animate({'width':'+=1%'},500);
```

it works but the element is animated on the right and not from the center of himself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to move the element also.

```
<a class="animate" style="display:block; width:300px; border:1px solid #000; position:fixed; top:50px; left:50px;">hey</a>
jQuery(".animate").animate({'width':'0px', 'left':'200px'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ysbg/

### New Information

So you mean something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/7Ysbg/2/

```
jQuery(".animate").click( function(){
    var w = jQuery(".animate").width();
    var new_w = jQuery(".animate").width()*1.5;
    var left = jQuery(".animate").offset().left - ((new_w - w)/2);
    jQuery(".animate").animate({'width':new_w+'px', 'left':left+'px'}, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: sorry i need exactly the opposite ... you animate from n to 0 i need from n to +1 right +1 left

Comment: Changed code above.  You can change the 1.5 to 1.1 or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just animate not only the width but also the position of the element. For example you can animate the `left` property. In this case you element should have `position` set to `relative` or `absolute`.

```
var width = $('.animate').width();
$('.animate').animate({
    width: width*1.01,
    left: width*0.005
},500);
```

Comment: need i to set position:relative or absolute? cause as taken is not working for me

Comment: Sorry for the edit @bjornd.  I didn't mean to put that on yours, but it wouldn't let me undo it.